# Iterate through a vector column C++

Tags: c++, vector, 2d

I am wanting to iterate through my entire column that contains the type double and divide each value by the size of the column. This will give me the frequency. I would have not issue doing this in an array or any other datatype. I am still learning about the vectors. Here is the 2D vector type that I am trying to manipulate

```
vector<pair<char, double>> output;
```

Comment: This isn't 2D. It's two copies of 1D, not the product of two times 1D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have C++11:

```
for (auto & p : output)
{
   cout << p.first << " " << p.second << "\n";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

or with C++03

```
for (std::vector<std::pair<char, double> >::iterator it = output.begin(); 
     it != output.end(); ++it)
{
   cout << it .first << " " << it .second << "\n";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can treat a vector just like an array, and access the elements using `[]`. For example:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < output.size(); ++i)
{
    pair<char, double>& element = output[i]; // access element i in the vector
    cout << element.first; // prints the first member of the pair
    cout << element.second; // prints the second member of the pair
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> std::pair is a struct template that provides a way to store two
>   heterogeneous objects as a single unit.

if you have a vector of `pairs` this means you will access data through [pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) interface . You can get first data of pair via `first` member and second via `second`.

```
for(std::vector<std::pair <char, double> >::const_iterator vpci = arg.begin(); 
    vpci != arg.end(); ++vpci) {
        cout << vpci->first << "->" << vpci->second;
}
```

or even better, maybe create a template:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void prn_vecOfPair(const std::vector<std::pair <T1, T2> > &arg, string sep ="") {
    for(std::vector<std::pair <T1, T2> >::const_iterator vpci = arg.begin(); 
        vpci != arg.end(); ++vpci) {
        cout << vpci->first << "->" << vpci->second << sep;
    }
}
```

in C++11 this (as usual) can be done much easier:

```
for (auto & i : output)
{
   cout << i->first << "->" << i->second << "\n";
}
```

Comment: A pair isn't a specific tuple. Pairs can be standard layout more generally than tuples.